# RHEL 5 YUM Python Throwing Traceback and Timeout errors

Tags: redhat, python, yum, rhel5

I know, the first thing I should do is upgrade to RHEL 6 or 7, but unfortunately, I'm stuck on it for the time being. I have been running into this error using any `yum` commands. The `rpm` command works just fine, so I think an update got snuck in by accident by someone else, but no one is willing to fess up to it. Here is the output for `yum update` but it also gives the same error for all yum commands, even `yum` itself.

```
[root@servername00 ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 309, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 157, in main
    base.getOptionsConfig(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 187, in getOptionsConfig
    self.conf
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 665, in <lambda>
    conf = property(fget=lambda self: self._getConfig(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 254, in _getConfig
    self.plugins.run('init')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 179, in run
    func(conduitcls(self, self.base, conf, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/rhnplugin.py", line 125, in init_hook
    login_info = up2dateAuth.getLoginInfo(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 219, in getLoginInfo
    login(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 170, in login
    server = rhnserver.RhnServer(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/rhnserver.py", line 155, in __init__
    self._server = rpcServer.getServer(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/rpcServer.py", line 156, in getServer
    timeout=timeout)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

I'm not sure what I need to fix, or do with this to correct those errors, or what to check up on the webs to diagnose.

Comment: What does `python -V` return?

Comment: The version of Python: `Python 2.4.3`

Comment: My hypothesis was that someone had upgraded the system Python and in turn broke yum, but 2.4.3 is "correct" for RHEL 5.

Comment: One of my fellow employees went in and disabled the `rhnplugin` for YUM and now it is at least not throwing the error on first try.

Answer (score 0):

A fellow employee of mine, helped me with this issue, and it was something to do with `rhnplugin`. Once it was disabled/removed, yum was able to do its work.